# Catalina duplicates files open in text editors after restart

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, file, text-editor

**Problem:** After macOS update to Catalina, when the computer shuts down with a text editor open (VSCode) or IDE (webstorm and the likes), it automatically generates files adding a `2` . eg `index.html` becomes `index 2.html`

The files were saved, committed (using git) and even pushed to GitHub, before the shutdown.

**Question:** How do you ensure/prevent files from autogenerating?

Comment: No, they were saved and committed (using git) and even pushed to GitHub